# Desert deck, waterless maintenance, no ‘beauty of the wood’, can I sand and paint @ 3-yr intervals?

Tags: paint, deck, sanding, preparation

I have a 10-year old deck, 20-feet in the air, with peeling paint. It is surrounded by white stucco ( *below also )* so I can not afford to have chemical stripper running down the stucco and pressure wash is a bad use of precious water. 8x10’ size. I cannot access the bottom of 60% of the boards.( *installed over a metal sheet which drains into a gutter* ).

Weather conditions are summer sun, a light dusting of snow. 90 ( *summer* ) days of daily, 15-minute hard rain. 15-30% humidity the rest of the year. Highest temps rarely up to 100. Winter freezes some but very rarely single digits.

After reading here, I believe a possible maintenance option is to sand and paint every 3-4 years to repair peeling and bubbling. I make/restore furniture as a hobby but have no deck experience. I am aware of the lawsuits for Deckover and Deck Restore so am wary of ‘miracle’ fixes. I don’t care if the color is uneven or the grain doesn’t show. I am all about preserving the boards.

Can you advise which false assumptions I am making ?

If my plan is reasonable, which paint properties  make the most durable deck paint finish ? ( *high in acrylic? hi-gloss latex etc?* )